# Local storage javascript variable to php

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

Thanks for your time in reading this post.

I am facing issues while passing javascript variable to php file.

Please look at the below code for your reference which i have written in checkout.php.

```
    $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "checkout.php",
data: localStorage.getItem("simpleCart_items"),
success: function(data) {
console.log("result"+JSON.stringify(data))
```

My php code :

```
<?php $data=$_POST['data']; echo $data;?>
```

Redirect is happening but $data value is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{ data: data }` is passed only to the first `checkout.php` call using POST method. When you redirect the user with `window.location.href` it has nothing to do with the previous call.

Depending on your use-case you could in the first call to `checkout.php` save `data` to session and the access it in the second call but it really depends what you're trying to do.

Edit: jQuery's data parameter is the entire payload you want to send to server. So if you were sending:

```
$.post({
    data: {
        message: 'Hello'
    }
    ...
});
```

It'll be available in `checkout.php` as `$_POST['message']` and not `$_POST['data']['message']`.

Comment: Updated the code and fetching local storage from the same page.  But still i could not able to print the $data value.  Please have a look

Comment: I updated the answer. Open dev tools and see what does the request body looks like.

Comment: Thanks martin $.redirect('checkout.php', {'arg1': data}); i used and its working now.  Your first point helped me a lot.